# Magento 2 : I Want to Display All Catagory and Sub Category in Layerd Navigation

Tags: magento2, category, layered-navigation

I want to display all category in layered navigation in Magento 2.

**For example :**
Clothing I have 3 sub categories then I want to display all three categories with subcategory.

Answer (score 0):

enable Anchor option under categories

Answer (score 0):

You need go over:

1. **Stores->Configuration->CATALOG->Catalog**.
2. Show **Category Top Navigation**
3. Change this :[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay. It is not working for me if the depth is 0 it is displaying only subcategories of the selected category. I want to display all category and subcategory

Comment: So change the depth to greater, example 4 or 6 or 8, I showed where to change.

Comment: How to get know where the getItem function is defined in Magento 2.